Flask unable to connect to Redis & Celery with Docker-Compose
I am able to run celery shared tasks in the flask (called web) container's flask shell without issue (docker-compose exec web flask shell), however they time out when running in a route. Suspecting that the redis container could not be reached, I ran the following in both the container's flask shell and inside a route. I found the redis container's ip with docker network inspect <network name>.
import redis
print(f'{redis.Redis(host="172.22.0.2", port=6379).ping()=}')
print(f'{redis.Redis(host='redis', port=6379).ping()=}')

The ip reference runs properly in both flask shell and route. However, the container name reference fails only in the route. I do not understand how the name can properly resolve in the flask shell, but not the route.
Full error log when trying to call above print statements in the route:
web_1            | redis.Redis(host="172.23.0.2", port=6379).ping()=True
web_1            | [2024-07-24 14:14:08 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Error handling request /main/test_task
web_1            | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 464, in resolve
web_1            |     return _proxy.query(name, rdtype, raise_on_no_answer=raises,
web_1            |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 420, in query
web_1            |     return end()
web_1            |            ^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 399, in end
web_1            |     raise result[1]
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 380, in step
web_1            |     a = fun(*args, **kwargs)
web_1            |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/dns/resolver.py", line 1364, in query
web_1            |     return self.resolve(
web_1            |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/dns/resolver.py", line 1321, in resolve
web_1            |     timeout = self._compute_timeout(start, lifetime, resolution.errors)
web_1            |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/dns/resolver.py", line 1075, in _compute_timeout
web_1            |     raise LifetimeTimeout(timeout=duration, errors=errors)
web_1            | dns.resolver.LifetimeTimeout: The resolution lifetime expired after 5.106 seconds: Server Do53:127.0.0.11@53 answered udp() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignore_errors'; Server Do53:127.0.0.11@53 answered udp() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignore_errors'; Server Do53:127.0.0.11@53 answered udp() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignore_errors'; Server Do53:127.0.0.11@53 answered udp() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignore_errors'; Server Do53:127.0.0.11@53 answered udp() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignore_errors'; Server Do53:127.0.0.11@53 answered udp() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignore_errors'
web_1            | 
web_1            | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
web_1            | 
web_1            | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 264, in connect
web_1            |     sock = self.retry.call_with_retry(
web_1            |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/retry.py", line 46, in call_with_retry
web_1            |     return do()
web_1            |            ^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 265, in <lambda>
web_1            |     lambda: self._connect(), lambda error: self.disconnect(error)
web_1            |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 595, in _connect
web_1            |     for res in socket.getaddrinfo(
web_1            |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 559, in getaddrinfo
web_1            |     qname, addrs = _getaddrinfo_lookup(host, family, flags)
web_1            |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 530, in _getaddrinfo_lookup
web_1            |     raise err
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 519, in _getaddrinfo_lookup
web_1            |     answer = resolve(host, qfamily, False, use_network=use_network)
web_1            |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 472, in resolve
web_1            |     _raise_new_error(EAI_EAGAIN_ERROR)
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 101, in _raise_new_error
web_1            |     raise error_instance.__class__(*error_instance.args)
web_1            | socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Lookup timed out
web_1            | 
web_1            | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
web_1            | 
web_1            | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 55, in handle
web_1            |     self.handle_request(listener_name, req, client, addr)
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 108, in handle_request
web_1            |     respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
web_1            |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1478, in __call__
web_1            |     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
web_1            |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1458, in wsgi_app
web_1            |     response = self.handle_exception(e)
web_1            |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1455, in wsgi_app
web_1            |     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
web_1            |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 869, in full_dispatch_request
web_1            |     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
web_1            |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 867, in full_dispatch_request
web_1            |     rv = self.dispatch_request()
web_1            |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 852, in dispatch_request
web_1            |     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
web_1            |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 290, in decorated_view
web_1            |     return current_app.ensure_sync(func)(*args, **kwargs)
web_1            |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/app/web/main/views.py", line 75, in test_task
nginx_1          | 172.23.0.1 - - [24/Jul/2024:14:14:08 +0000] "GET /main/test_task HTTP/1.1" 500 141 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
web_1            |     print(f'{redis.Redis(host="redis", port=6379).ping()=}')
web_1            |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/commands/core.py", line 1216, in ping
web_1            |     return self.execute_command("PING", **kwargs)
web_1            |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 533, in execute_command
web_1            |     conn = self.connection or pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
web_1            |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 1086, in get_connection
web_1            |     connection.connect()
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 270, in connect
web_1            |     raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
web_1            | redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error -3 connecting to redis:6379. Lookup timed out.

Full error log when trying to call task_test.delay() in the route:
web_1            | [2024-07-24 12:54:11 +0000] [12] [ERROR] Error handling request /main/test_task
web_1            | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 464, in resolve
web_1            |     return _proxy.query(name, rdtype, raise_on_no_answer=raises,
web_1            |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 420, in query
web_1            |     return end()
web_1            |            ^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 399, in end
web_1            |     raise result[1]
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 380, in step
web_1            |     a = fun(*args, **kwargs)
web_1            |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/dns/resolver.py", line 1364, in query
web_1            |     return self.resolve(
web_1            |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/dns/resolver.py", line 1321, in resolve
web_1            |     timeout = self._compute_timeout(start, lifetime, resolution.errors)
web_1            |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/dns/resolver.py", line 1075, in _compute_timeout
web_1            |     raise LifetimeTimeout(timeout=duration, errors=errors)
web_1            | dns.resolver.LifetimeTimeout: The resolution lifetime expired after 5.106 seconds: Server Do53:127.0.0.11@53 answered udp() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignore_errors'; Server Do53:127.0.0.11@53 answered udp() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignore_errors'; Server Do53:127.0.0.11@53 answered udp() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignore_errors'; Server Do53:127.0.0.11@53 answered udp() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignore_errors'; Server Do53:127.0.0.11@53 answered udp() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignore_errors'; Server Do53:127.0.0.11@53 answered udp() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignore_errors'
web_1            | 
web_1            | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
web_1            | 
web_1            | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 264, in connect
web_1            |     sock = self.retry.call_with_retry(
web_1            |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/retry.py", line 46, in call_with_retry
web_1            |     return do()
web_1            |            ^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 265, in <lambda>
web_1            |     lambda: self._connect(), lambda error: self.disconnect(error)
web_1            |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 595, in _connect
web_1            |     for res in socket.getaddrinfo(
web_1            |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 559, in getaddrinfo
web_1            |     qname, addrs = _getaddrinfo_lookup(host, family, flags)
web_1            |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 530, in _getaddrinfo_lookup
web_1            |     raise err
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 519, in _getaddrinfo_lookup
web_1            |     answer = resolve(host, qfamily, False, use_network=use_network)
web_1            |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 472, in resolve
web_1            |     _raise_new_error(EAI_EAGAIN_ERROR)
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 101, in _raise_new_error
web_1            |     raise error_instance.__class__(*error_instance.args)
web_1            | socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Lookup timed out
web_1            | 
web_1            | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
web_1            | 
web_1            | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 127, in reconnect_on_error
web_1            |     yield
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 177, in _consume_from
web_1            |     self._pubsub.subscribe(key)
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 916, in subscribe
web_1            |     ret_val = self.execute_command("SUBSCRIBE", *new_channels.keys())
web_1            |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 749, in execute_command
web_1            |     self.connection = self.connection_pool.get_connection(
web_1            |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 1086, in get_connection
web_1            |     connection.connect()
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 270, in connect
web_1            |     raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
web_1            | redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error -3 connecting to redis:6379. Lookup timed out.
web_1            | 
web_1            | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
web_1            | 
web_1            | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 264, in connect
web_1            |     sock = self.retry.call_with_retry(
web_1            |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/retry.py", line 46, in call_with_retry
web_1            |     return do()
web_1            |            ^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 265, in <lambda>
web_1            |     lambda: self._connect(), lambda error: self.disconnect(error)
web_1            |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 595, in _connect
web_1            |     for res in socket.getaddrinfo(
web_1            |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 559, in getaddrinfo
web_1            |     qname, addrs = _getaddrinfo_lookup(host, family, flags)
web_1            |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 530, in _getaddrinfo_lookup
web_1            |     raise err
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 519, in _getaddrinfo_lookup
web_1            |     answer = resolve(host, qfamily, False, use_network=use_network)
web_1            |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 472, in resolve
web_1            |     _raise_new_error(EAI_EAGAIN_ERROR)
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 101, in _raise_new_error
web_1            |     raise error_instance.__class__(*error_instance.args)
web_1            | socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Lookup timed out
web_1            | 
web_1            | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
web_1            | 
web_1            | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 472, in _reraise_as_library_errors
web_1            |     yield
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 798, in send_task
web_1            |     self.backend.on_task_call(P, task_id)
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 373, in on_task_call
web_1            |     self.result_consumer.consume_from(task_id)
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 169, in consume_from
web_1            |     return self.start(task_id)
web_1            |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 147, in start
web_1            |     self._consume_from(initial_task_id)
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 176, in _consume_from
web_1            |     with self.reconnect_on_error():
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/contextlib.py", line 158, in __exit__
web_1            |     self.gen.throw(value)
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 130, in reconnect_on_error
web_1            |     self._ensure(self._reconnect_pubsub, ())
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 384, in ensure
web_1            |     return retry_over_time(
web_1            |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 318, in retry_over_time
web_1            |     return fun(*args, **kwargs)
web_1            |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 106, in _reconnect_pubsub
web_1            |     metas = self.backend.client.mget(self.subscribed_to)
web_1            |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/commands/core.py", line 2015, in mget
web_1            |     return self.execute_command("MGET", *args, **options)
web_1            |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 533, in execute_command
web_1            |     conn = self.connection or pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
web_1            |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 1086, in get_connection
web_1            |     connection.connect()
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 270, in connect
web_1            |     raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
web_1            | redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error -3 connecting to redis:6379. Lookup timed out.
web_1            | 
web_1            | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
web_1            | 
web_1            | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 55, in handle
web_1            |     self.handle_request(listener_name, req, client, addr)
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 108, in handle_request
web_1            |     respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
web_1            |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1478, in __call__
web_1            |     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
web_1            |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1458, in wsgi_app
web_1            |     response = self.handle_exception(e)
web_1            |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1455, in wsgi_app
web_1            |     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
web_1            |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 869, in full_dispatch_request
web_1            |     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
web_1            |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 867, in full_dispatch_request
web_1            |     rv = self.dispatch_request()
web_1            |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 852, in dispatch_request
web_1            |     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
web_1            |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 290, in decorated_view
web_1            |     return current_app.ensure_sync(func)(*args, **kwargs)
web_1            |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/app/web/main/views.py", line 79, in test_task
web_1            |     task_test.delay()
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 444, in delay
web_1            |     return self.apply_async(args, kwargs)
web_1            |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 594, in apply_async
web_1            |     return app.send_task(
web_1            |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 796, in send_task
web_1            |     with P.connection._reraise_as_library_errors():
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/contextlib.py", line 158, in __exit__
web_1            |     self.gen.throw(value)
web_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 476, in _reraise_as_library_errors
web_1            |     raise ConnectionError(str(exc)) from exc
web_1            | kombu.exceptions.OperationalError: Error -3 connecting to redis:6379. Lookup timed out.

docker-compose.yml
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - redacted
      dockerfile: ./docker/web/Dockerfile
    command: /start
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    expose:
      - 5000
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - FLASK_APP=app
    depends_on:
      - redis

  redis:
    image: redis:7-alpine
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'

  celery_worker:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - redacted
      dockerfile: ./docker/web/Dockerfile
    command: /start-celeryworker
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - FLASK_APP=celery_app
    depends_on:
      - redis

  celery_beat:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - redacted
      dockerfile: ./docker/web/Dockerfile]
    command: /start-celerybeat
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - FLASK_APP=celery_app
    depends_on:
      - redis

  flower:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - redacted
      dockerfile: ./docker/web/Dockerfile
    command: /start-flower
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - FLASK_APP=celery_app
    ports:
      - '5555:5555'
    depends_on:
      - redis

  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '443:443'
      - '80:80'
    depends_on:
      - web

web > init.py
...
from flask_celeryext import FlaskCeleryExt
from web.celery_utils import make_celery

ext_celery = FlaskCeleryExt(create_celery_app=make_celery)
...

def create_app(config_name=None):
    if config_name is None:
        config_name = os.environ.get('FLASK_CONFIG', 'development')

    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    # set config
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])

    # set up extensions
    ext_celery.init_app(app)
    ...

    # register blueprints
    from .main import main as main_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)
    ...

    # shell context for flask cli
    @app.shell_context_processor
    def ctx():
        return {'app':app, 'db':db}

    return app

celery_app.py
from web import create_app, ext_celery

app = create_app(config_name='development')
celery = ext_celery.celery

app.py
from web import create_app, ext_celery

app = create_app(config_name='development')
celery = ext_celery.celery

web > config.py
import os
from pathlib import Path
from kombu import Queue
import json
from datetime import timedelta
from celery.schedules import crontab

class BaseConfig:
    BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).parent.parent
    TESTING = False
    FLASKY_ADMIN = os.environ.get('FLASKY_ADMIN')
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')

    BROKER_URL = 'redis://redis:6379/0'
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://redis:6379/0'
    # Force all queues to be explicitly listed in 'CELERY_TASK_QUEUES' to help prevent typos
    CELERY_TASK_CREATE_MISSING_QUEUES = False
    CELERY_TASK_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'default'
    CELERY_TASK_QUEUES = (
        Queue('default'),
        Queue('high_priority'),
        Queue('low_priority'),
    )

    CELERY_TASK_ROUTES = {
        'web.main.tasks.add': {
            'queue': 'default',
        },
    }
    CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
        'send-email-reminder': {
            'task': 'default:email_reminder',
            'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=12, day_of_week='mon,wed,fri') # Time is UTC
        }
    }


class DevelopmentConfig(BaseConfig):
    DEBUG = True
    TESTING = False # When True, prevents Celery tasks from working properly (flask-mail doesnt work, 
                    # and shared tasks like add() perform synchronously, not asynchronously).

    CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {}


config = {
    'development': DevelopmentConfig
}

web > main > tasks.py
from celery import shared_task


logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

@shared_task(name='default:task_test')
def task_test():
    logger.info('about to sleep...')
    time.sleep(5)
    logger.info('executing...')
    print('abc 123')
    time.sleep(5)
    logger.info('done.')

web > main > views.py
from . import main
from .tasks import task_test

@main.route('/test_task', methods=['GET'])
def test_task():
  print(f'{os.system(f'ping redis')=}') # returns True (after I apt install iputils-ping)

  print(f'{redis.Redis(host="172.23.0.2", port=6379).ping()=}')
  print(f'{redis.Redis(host="redis", port=6379).ping()=}') # fails here unless commented out, but this function executes properly in flask shell

  task_test.delay() # fails here, but this function executes properly in flask shell
  return ''

